# Restore sql server .bak file to different sql server versions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application in C#  that use a sql server database .The first time the application is executed , he restore a .bak file to sql server.
But the problem is that this .bak file is created using a specific version of sql server.

Is there any way to make this application work , regardless of sql server version , I mean to restore this bak file to sql server regardless of the version ?

Thank you !

Comment: Only if your bak file is of a lower/equal version than the current sql-server. But not sure about version prior to 2005 restored on 2014.

Comment: what about a 2012 version to be restored on 2005 ?

Comment: You'd be better off creating a database project in visual studio, and creating a `dacpac` that can merge or overwrite an existing database.  This could be dangerous allowing your app to do something like this, though.

Comment: @Alex SQL Server 2012 version can not be stored on SQL Server  2005

Comment: @alex, no.  SQL Server backups can only be restored to the same server version or a newer version, never to an older version. You'd have to create your DDL creation scripts and execute those against the server or create a dacpac for similar functionality.

Comment: You can restore to same or newer versions of sql server. Just do few more steps. Change compatibility level of the restored database. ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;                                                      90 for 'SQL Server 2005'
100 for 'SQL Server 2008/R2'
110 for 'SQL Server 2012'
120 for 'SQL Server 2014    second step : run DBCC CHECKDB to check  logical and physical integrity of all the objects in restored database. if more error comes then restoration is done successfully.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restore a backup taken on a new version to an old SQL Server version. Generate the backup on a downlevel version or use a different data copy mechanism such as SQL scripts.